# Store external API expire time in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, custom

I use ajax to get the access token from the external API. How can I store the expired time across the site and the ajax only call again when the session expired?

**test.js**

/helloworld/index/display is the controller that will get the input from Store -> Configuration and call the external API by using cURL

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/helloworld/index/display",
    type: "GET",
    complete: function (response) {
        access_token = response.responseText;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use localstorage for that.

Comment: @Hitesh Agrawal for localstorage, each customer will have a different access token. However, I would like to use only 1 access token key across the site and it will reset when the session expired

Comment: you want to use only 1 access token for all customer?